# Question about weak convergence, $\lbrace f(x_{n}) \rbrace$ converges for all $n$, then $x_{n} \rightharpoonup x$

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I found the following question in my textbook:

Let $E$ be a reflexive space, and let $\lbrace x_{n} \rbrace \subset E$ be a sequence such that $\lbrace f(x_{n}) \rbrace$ converges for all $ f \in E^{*}  $. Show that exists a $x \in E$ such that $x_{n} \rightharpoonup x$.

I can show that $x_{n}$ bounded (in the norm topology), then, using the fact that every bounded subset of a reflexive space is sequentially compact, I have a subsenquence weakly convrgent. But, I can't show that the entire sequence converges in the weak sense.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $\Lambda:E^*\to\Bbb C$ by $\Lambda f = \lim f(x_n)$. Then $\Lambda$ is certainly linear. You say you've shown $||x_n||$ is bounded; that implies that $\Lambda$ is bounded. So $\Lambda $ is a bounded linear functional on $E^*$, which is to say $\Lambda\in E^{**}$.

But $E$ is reflexive, which says that $E^{**}=E$. Except of course that's not a literal equality; saying $E^{**}=E$ says that if $\Lambda\in E^{**}$ there exists $x\in E$ so that $\Lambda f=f(x)$ for all $f\in E^*$. So $x_n\to x$ weakly.

Comment: Thanks David. I should have thought of something like this :)